# Access Properties File in a Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, properties, path, filenotfoundexception

I have a java file inside src/test/java/com/pp/utils. I need to access a properties file example.properties that is inside src/test/resources from this Java file.

I tried it with :

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {

    input = new FileInputStream("example.properties");

// load a properties file
    prop.load(input);

// get the property value and print it out
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("key1"));

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This gives a FileNotFound Exception. What should be the path? Or where else can I place the properties file so that it gets picked up?

Comment: ALWAYS get a resource as stream to access your properties file

Answer (score 2):

try

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/example.properties");
```

For clarity this assumes you properties file is in /src/test/resources, that is the root of the classpath, hence the /example.properties.

Comment: I tried the above. When debugged, the inputStream is null.

Comment: @Tunaki as the question has been asked the example.properties is at the root of the classpth i.e. /example.properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
 InputStream  addrStream = <current-class>.class.getResourceAsStream("example.properties");

            prop .load(addrStream);
```

if my class name is PropertyUtil

```
InputStream  addrStream = PropertyUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("example.properties");

                prop .load(addrStream);
```

or

```
 InputStream  addrStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("example.properties");

                    prop .load(addrStream);
```

use above first code if you are using properties code in `main method`.